# Getting the "Loading ..." div to show for jqgrid datatype local with virtual scroll

Tags: jqgrid

When using the "virtual scroll" feature of jqgrid to only create elements that are displayed for large data sets there is a lag while it builds up the cells.

If you are using ajax to fetch data the loading display appears but if the datatype is local the display doesn't get a chance to update with the loading message and user sees a blank table for a while until it renders.

Are there any suggestions for how to get the loading message to show for this scenario? Are there any events or hooks into jqgrid for adding a timeout to get the browser a chance to render the loading message?